# Inserting into array with known positions and values

Tags: python, numpy

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([2,2])

b = np.array([[0,0],
              [0,1],
              [1,0],
              [1,1]])

values = np.array([[10,20,30,40]]).T

#some function
#desired outcome for a as numpy array:

a = [[10,20],
     [30,40]]
```

As you can see from code, I have a zero value array, which I would like to fill with values. My question is does NumPy offer any function for this? I would like to find an elegant way, before using for loop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On simple approach is to use numpy indexing:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.zeros([2, 2])

b = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1]])

values = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])

rows, cols = zip(*b)
a[rows, cols] = values
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[10. 20.]
 [30. 40.]]
```

An alternative, is to use the [csr_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.csr_matrix) constructor from scipy:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csr_matrix

a = np.zeros([2, 2])

b = np.array([[0, 0],
              [0, 1],
              [1, 0],
              [1, 1]])

values = np.array([10, 20, 30, 40])

a = csr_matrix((values, zip(*b)), a.shape).todense()
print(a)
```

**Output**

```
[[10 20]
 [30 40]]
```

Comment: first example is realy simple:) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One way would be with [`np.put_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.put_along_axis.html):

```
np.put_along_axis(a, b, values, 0)
```

---

Or since `a` is an array of zeros, we could also use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html). We just need to modify the `indices` to match the dimension of `a`:

```
np.add.at(a, tuple(zip(*b)), values.ravel())
```

---

```
print(a)
array([[10., 20.],
       [30., 40.]])
```